# How to specify android sdk root for building with Expo EAS in managed workflow?

Tags: expo

When I'm building my react-native project locally with expo's eas, I'm getting

```
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at (path)/build/android/local.properties
```

Since I'm in managed workflow, there is no way I can access local.properties and set SDK root.

Setting ANDROID_SDK_ROOT variable like this:

```
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/bin/android-sdk sudo eas build --platform android --local
```

doesn't work either.

And I couldn't find any questions about that and documentation in Expo. I downloaded android sdk 30 using sdkmanager and placed in `/usr/local/bin/android-sdk` directory. How to specify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Env variables can be placed in eas.json:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.55.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {
      "env": {
        "ANDROID_SDK_ROOT": "/usr/local/bin/android-sdk"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```